# CMS or PHP framework for small developer maintained sites - content management through git?

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

I am building, and will be maintaining a small site as a personal project.

- I want be able to occasionally update a handful of pages, including
  regular posts to a blog, and be easily able to change the design of
  the site.

  Ideally I'd like to be able to manage all the content including
  posting blog articles through git, so I can write in pure text / HTML
  as I'm used to, and avoid the need to make changes through an online
  editor or admin area.

  At the same time, I want to keep the coding of this as simple as
  possible, such as writing an article as an html file and adding some
  metadata to a separate xml file.

Wordpress, get-simple CMS, concrete5 and the many others I've looked at don't cut it.

What methods are considered best to build small sites that only a developer will maintain, and allow fast and efficient ways to control every aspect of content and metadata.

I'm more familiar with PHP but if there are big advantages to python based systems then that's cool too.

Answer (score 0):

Better you have go with `JOOMLA` . This was best `CMS` and you can manage all the datas like Article, Blog Posts, etc..

This was also have user friendly administrator section. So any person including non-technical person can manage the website.

[Joomla Demo Administrator](http://demo.opensourcecms.com/joomla/administrator)

[Joomla Demo Site](http://www.opensourcecms.com/demo/1/38/Joomla)

```
ADMIN USERNAME: admin

ADMIN PASSWORD: demo123
```

Choice is urs... All the best...

Comment: Thanks, Joomla is certainly a great bit of kit, It's not really what I'm after. Too many features I don't need, and no way to do all the work from the command line.